# Using log4cxx with Visual Studio 2010. Application initialization error

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, log4cxx

I have succeeded to build the `log4cxx` library both in debug and release mode and created log4cxxd.lib and `log4cxx.lib` files. But when I try to use them with static linking in my visual C++ 2010 project I get

> The application failed to initialize properly (0xc0150002).

in debug mode. 
In release mode it just works fine. For debug configuration, I've added `log4cxxd.lib` as additional dependency and for release configuration I've added `log4cxx.lib`. I think it should also work in debug mode, but it does not.

Any ideas?

Comment: 0xc0150002 means that a dll could not be loaded. Chances are it's looking for a specific debug version of a DLL that isn't installed or available in the search path.

Comment: You are right Chet. The problem is the version. The lib and dll files were created for a previous project with Visual Studio 2008. I tested the debug library with visual C++ 2008 and it worked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on your application to determine what library is missing.